# Excel Generate Text based on adjacent value

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering if it was possible to generate text based on adjacent value like this table:

```
Column A    Column B(Count)
  Text 1       3
  Text 2       5
```

End result should be when a script runs:

```
Column A
  Text 1
  Text 1
  Text 1
  Text 2
  Text 2
  Text 2
  Text 2
  Text 2
```

Been searching on Google for this and I can't find the result I was looking for.  I assume VBA Macros will do the trick?  For loops would be my guess.  Think of this as reversing the process of pivot table to find unique values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With data in columns **A** and **B**, this tiny macro:

```
Sub Repetition()
   Dim N As Long, i As Long, K As Long
   N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   K = 1

   For i = 1 To N
      For j = 1 To Cells(i, 2).Value
         Cells(K, 3).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
         K = K + 1
      Next j
   Next i
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]

Comment: I really really thank you Gary for that.  This will be useful in my work.  And learned my first VBA for practical application. :D

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA for this.  You can just put a formula in the adjacent cell:

```
=(A1 & " " & B1)
```

Unless you really want to use VBA.  In which case, this answer does not apply.

Comment: He did not want a concatenation.  The OP wanted to put in column b the number of times column a should be repeated.  So "Text 1" would be repeated 3 times.  And "Text 2" 5 times.

Comment: Ok.  Clearly, I did not understand that.  Sorry...  Just trying to help.